# How Do I Improve on Elementwise Calculation for R Speed

Tags: r

The following below is a sample of something I'm currently computing. This gives the expected result, but I don't think is the best use of code. Does anyone see a better way this could be written that avoids loops. I create the objects as I do here to take advantage of some elementwise calculations, which is faster, but this code just doesn't feel like it's best, although I am struggling to find an alternative.

This code lives inside an optimization routine that gets called many times, so object creation here could be expensive.

```
a <- runif(5)
b <- runif(5)
Q <- 7
nds <- runif(Q)
```

#### Relevant portion of code to improve

```
 A <- do.call(rbind, replicate(Q, a, simplify = FALSE))
 betas <- do.call(rbind, replicate(Q, b, simplify = FALSE)) - nds
 pr <- plogis(-A * betas)
```

Comment: I don't think this code is doing what you expect it to do. Using `replicate` like this is certainly a little strange because there's nothing changing in the loop as it's written, it's acting more like a `rep` than anything else. You'll get different values for each loop of the `replicate` if you include the `runif` inside the call but defining it outside of the loop means it's fixed and won't change. Is that what you intended?

Comment: For example, this code produces the exact same thing and is much faster because it avoids loops and rbinds, but isn't at all randomized: `A <- matrix(rep(a, Q), nrow = Q, byrow = TRUE)`